# Forward Traffic to virtual box (Genymotion)

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, android, netfilter

I am running an Android virtual machine (Samsung Galaxy S10 & android 10.0 API29) using Genymotion. I have a VPN running there (OpenVPN protocol). Now I am running all this over my Debian based Linux. I have iptables in my Linux machine and as well as in Android VM.
Now I want to forward the entire traffic from my Linux Machine to Android through VPN and since Linux is connected to LAN so every traffic must come back to Host Machine(Linux), when it comes I  want to forward it to the main gateway to access the internet.

Comment: That's not VPN, but requires NAT.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes I know I will have to make some NAT rules, but I am not that good in iptables

Comment: Try to bridge the VM directly to an external LAN IP, then it doesn't need NAT. See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002738297-How-to-connect-to-a-Genymotion-Desktop-virtual-device-remotely-with-ADB-

Comment: @MartinZeitler I can do that but what about flowing the traffic from VPN?

Comment: Running a VPN on the same host or the LAN is commonly pretty pointless. And you can configure a VPN on the emulator, if it has to connect to the outside world through VPN. Such network bridges usually have 3 modes they can run in ...